# Set up multi-head environnement on FreeBSD running X.org

Tags: unix, multiple-monitors, xorg, freebsd

My goal is to set up a multi-head environnement: I need to have an extended desktop available on both screens with the ability to drag and drop windows from one screen to another. The left screen is on `VGA` port and the right one is plugged into the `HDMI` port.

I tried playing around with `xorg.conf` but it appears I cannot set up the proper configuration for the multi-head to work.

Here is my `xorg.conf`:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/local/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/local/lib/X11/fonts/misc/"
    FontPath     "/usr/local/lib/X11/fonts/TTF/"
    FontPath     "/usr/local/lib/X11/fonts/OTF"
    FontPath     "/usr/local/lib/X11/fonts/Type1/"
    FontPath     "/usr/local/lib/X11/fonts/100dpi/"
    FontPath     "/usr/local/lib/X11/fonts/75dpi/"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "dbe"
    Load  "dri"
    Load  "dri2"
    Load  "extmod"
    Load  "record"
    Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier   "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "evdev"
        Option       "XkbLayout" "fr"
        #Option      "XkbModel" "pc105"
        #Option      "Device" "/dev/ukbd0"
        #Option      "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/sysmouse"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "ShadowFB"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DefaultRefresh"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ModeSetClearScreen"    # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "vesa"
    VendorName  "Intel Corporation"
    BoardName   "Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I've read [somewhere](http://www.freebsddiary.org/xorg-two-screens.php) that I need both the `Virtual` and `Modes` directives set up so I've amended the configuration as such :

```
Section "Screen"
    # ...
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
        Virtual   3600 1080
        Modes     "1920x1080" "1680x1050"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

The result was a fuzzy image running on the main screen. I was able to move the mouse though and see that the desktop is actually extended. But it's unusable and running on one screen only.

I also have installed `XRandr` as per [this documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multihead#RandR) but the output of `$ xrandr -q` is as such:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1920 x 1200, maximum 1920 x 1200
default connected 1920x1200+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1200      0.00* 
   1600x1200      0.00  
   1280x1024      0.00  
   1024x768       0.00  
   800x600        0.00  
   640x480        0.00
```

So I see there's only one screen detected and therefore, I cannot run the following command to display both screen as per my will:

```
$ xrandr --output <RightScreen> --right-of default
```

As I don't know the name of `<RightScreen>`.

The weirdest thing being that, on reboot with right `HDMI` screen plugged in, the boot appears on the right screen and nothing appears on the main (left) screen. When I log in, XFCE is unable to display anything on the right screen and I'm left with both screens unusable. The only solution is to manually shutdown the computer (by pressing the button), unplug the right screen and boot again.

What am I missing? I am completely new in Linux world, let alone `FreeBSD` so bear with me if I am doing something completely wrong.

Any help would be kindly appreciated. Thanks!